Running an async task in the background after others finished
I have X asynchronous tasks that are executed using asyncio.gather(), and they are created in a loop. Once these tasks are finished, I need to run a single asynchronous task to perform some actions. However, I don't want to wait for this task to finish before moving on to the next iteration (So i can create new X tasks).
What would be the best approach to handle this scenario?
Not doing await on the single task might cause a situation where its not being called.

You can achieve this by using asyncio.create_task() to schedule the single asynchronous task after your asyncio.gather() call without awaiting it.
You can implement this by the following:
import asyncio

async def main():
    while True:
        # Create and run X tasks concurrently
        tasks = [asyncio.create_task(some_async_function(i)) for i in range(X)]
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        
        # Run the background task without awaiting it
        asyncio.create_task(background_task())

        # Optionally, add a condition to break the loop or continue as needed
        if some_condition():
            break

async def some_async_function(i):
    # Your async task implementation
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print(f'Task {i} completed')

async def background_task():
    # Your background task implementation
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print('Background task completed')

async def some_condition():
    # Some condition to continue or break the loop
    return False  # Update with your actual condition

asyncio.run(main())

This should allow your background tasks to run without blocking creation of new tasks in your next iteration.
EDIT 1: I have modified the code in this edit to hopefully help with your issue.
async def main():
    background_tasks = []  # List to store background tasks

    while True:
        # Create and run X tasks concurrently
        tasks = [asyncio.create_task(some_async_function(i)) for i in range(X)]
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        
        # Schedule the background task and store it in the list
        background_task = asyncio.create_task(background_task_function())
        background_tasks.append(background_task)

        # Example condition to break the loop
        if some_condition():
            break

    # Await all background tasks to ensure they finish
    await asyncio.gather(*background_tasks)

async def some_async_function(i):
    # Your async task implementation
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print(f'Task {i} completed')

async def background_task_function():
    # Your background task implementation
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print('Background task completed')

async def some_condition():
    # Some condition to continue or break the loop
    return False  # Update with your actual condition

asyncio.run(main())

To ensure that the background tasks are allowed to finish even if the loop breaks, you can collect the background tasks and await them after breaking the loop. Once the loop is broken, await asyncio.gather(*background_tasks) ensures that all the background tasks finish before the program exits.

But in this implementation, if the break condition occurs, the program will break and stop. As a result, The task that were supposed to be running in the background will not finish.

might not now after update, how many tasks are you running?

Great, thank you! About the amount, i don't have a specific value, but it can range from 1 to lets say 300

just confirming that it did work?
